# ngOnInit having multiple NgRx store subscription

Tags: angular, subscribe

Am working on angular 13 version.I have 3 component.
Two of them having downtown list.While selecting these drop down, i will save selected value to **NgRx** **store**.
In my third component ,i have to subscribe selected dop-down value from the store.
Based on the above store value i need to pass these value as a param to my backed **API**

This is my **ngOnInit** code

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.co1figFacade.getSeleConSet().subscribe((data: string) => {
      if (data.length > 0) {
        this.cuConfSet = data;
      }

    });
     
    this.coFacade.getCurrentCoType().subscribe((data: string) => {
      if (data.length > 0) {
        this.conType = data;
      }
    
    });

    if(this.conType .length>0 && this.cuConfSet.length>0){
      
      this.getData(this.cuConfSet,this.conType );
    }
  }
```

How can i solve this issue

Am trying to do below steps

1.subscribing two method (**getSeleConSet** and **getCurrentCoType**)These two method return a string value.

2 if the two response are not null.i need to pass these two response as an argument to **getData** method

Answer (score 4):

you need to use `combineLatest` to connect both observables and then use `tap` to check and do something with the data returned.

```
ombineLatest(
  this.co1figFacade.getSeleConSet(),  
  this.coFacade.getCurrentCoType()
 )
.tap(([v1, v2]) => {
  if(v1 && v2) {
    this.getData(this.cuConfSet,this.conType );
  }
}).subscribe();
```